# Weird things happening when using ImageGrab.grab()

Tags: python, tkinter, screenshot

I have some code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageGrab

root = Tk()


def capture():
    x0 = canvas.winfo_rootx()
    y0 = canvas.winfo_rooty()
    x1 = x0 + canvas.winfo_width()
    y1 = y0 + canvas.winfo_height()

    im = ImageGrab.grab((x0, y0, x1, x2))
    im.save('mypic.png')  # Can also say im.show() to display it


canvas = Canvas(root, bg='red')
canvas.pack(padx=10, pady=10)

e = Entry(root)

canvas.create_window(canvas.canvasx(100), canvas.canvasy(100), window=e)

Button(root, text='Click a pic', command=capture).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

It makes mypic:

[image]

Which is part of my background
But i want it to make:[image]

Which is a screenshot of my screen.

I tried changing other parameters like `include_layeder_windows`, but it didn't change anything.
My problem is that grab() returns my background instead of my screen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you're using Mac OS. In Mac, an application by default cannot grab contents of other application's window. When trying to do so, it will grab the desktop background only. This could perhaps be observed e.g. when sharing screen over e.g. Zoom, without giving Zoom proper permissions.

To fix that, you need to go to "System Preferences" > "Privacy" > "Privacy" > "Screen Recording" and add your application there.